# Python: Sum values in col 1 if previous values in column 2 equals value in column 3 on each row

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, sumifs

My data is in a csv like this

```
ID  Date    Year    Home Team   Away Team   HP  AP
1   09/02   1966    Miami       Oakland     14  23
2   09/03   1966    Houston     Denver      45  7
3   09/10   1966    Oakland     Houston     31  0
4   09/27   1966    Houston     Oakland     18  10
5   10/20   1966    Oakland     Houston     21  18
```

On each row I want to sum the previously accumulated home and away points for both home team and away team.

I have used pandas groupby to get the home points for the home team and the away points for the away team similar to below

```
df1['HT_HP']=df1.groupby('Home Team')['HP'].apply(lambda x : x.shift().cumsum())
```

But I can't do it to get the previously scored away points for the home team and the previously scored home points for the away team.

so for the first Oakland Houston game there would be a column with Oakland 23 away points and a separate column for Houston 45 home points

```
Expected outcome:
ID  Date    Year    Home Team   Away Team   HP  AP  HT_AP  AT_HP
1   09/02   1966    Miami       Oakland     14  23  NaN    NaN
2   09/03   1966    Houston     Denver      45  7   NaN    NaN
3   09/10   1966    Oakland     Houston     31  0   23     45
4   09/27   1966    Houston     Oakland     18  10  0      31
5   10/20   1966    Oakland     Houston     21  18  33     63
```

I've tried this

```
df1['HT_AGS'] = df1.where(df1['AwayTeam']==df1['HomeTeam']).groupby('HomeTeam')['FTHG'].apply(lambda x : x.shift().cumsum())
```

This returns a full column of NaN values

In excel it would be something similar to sumifs(F1:F3,D1:D3,E4)

Comment: Why the miami oakland are both NaN?

Comment: There is no previous data to sum.

Comment: I have added more rows to the data so you can see that what the column is trying to achieve as the data increases. It doesn't include the current rows figures.

Comment: Are you sure 33 and 63 are the correct numbers?

Comment: Yes, for Oakland it would be adding the points scored away in the previous 2 away games, 23 and 10. And similarly for Houston, it would be the points scored at home for the previous 2 games which would be 45 and 18. Ideally i don't want to reference each team explicitly as there are many teams in the full data set.